# 3D rotation matrix with zero determinant

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, determinant, rotations

I have a 3D vector from the following shape:

\begin{gather}
p = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ z \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}

I had like to find a rotation matrix that will make p(1) and p(2) small non zero numbers and p(3) to be close to z value.

basically, by writting,

\begin{gather}
p' = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{13} \\ a_{23} \\ a_{33} \end{bmatrix} \cdot z
\end{gather}

Since it is rotational matrix I had expect it to have the same magnitude and therefore:

\begin{gather}
\sqrt{a_{11}^2 + a_{23}^2 + a_{33}^2} = 1
\end{gather}

The first idea that I had is something from the form of
\begin{gather}
p' = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \sin(\alpha) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \cos(\alpha) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sin(\alpha) \\ 1 \\ \cos(\alpha) \end{bmatrix} \cdot z \qquad, \alpha<1
\end{gather}

However, this matrix is problematic from my understanding because its determinant is zero and also the value of p'(2) is equal to z and I was looking for small value.

Is there any idea how to overcome these problems?

Thank you!

Comment: Since that vector already points in the $z$ direction, why not just make a small rotation about the $x$ followed by a small rotation about the $y$ axis?

Comment: You suggest to do like \begin{gather} R_{x}*R_{y}*g \end{gather}?

Comment: If the axis of your rotation is not the $z$ axis, then you can use this general formula for 3D-rotation about *any* axis with *any* angle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle